# Pause podcast on iPhone via Bluetooth with keyboard shortcut on Macbook Pro

Tags: music, bluetooth, podcasts.app

Maybe a long shot but this seems instinctively possible.

I listen to podcasts on my iPhone 6S via headphones that don't have a pause button on the cord. When people start speaking to me in the office I need to find the phone, push the home button and click pause.

Is it possible to connect the phone with my Macbook Pro via Bluetooth and then pause the podcast via a click/keyboard shortcut on my laptop? This would save me approximately 2 seconds per pause - these seconds add up over time(!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone else may be able to provide a better solution, but nothing I can think of avoids having to play the podcast directly from the MacBook Pro. That is, you play the file on your MBP and stream it to your iPhone for listening to (with or without your headphones). But, unless you need to listen to your podcast as you walk around the office, there's really no advantage of this over just plugging the headphones in directly to the MBP.

Nevertheless, if this is something you're interested in, you can check out the following software:

- [Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/)
- [AirPhones](http://airphonesapp.com)

Undoubtedly there will be other options out there too. My understanding is you can try Airfoil for free (not sure about AirPhones). But as I mentioned above, these options require you to play your podcasts from the MacBook Pro, so unless you want the freedom to get up / walk around, you would be better off just plugging your headphones into your Mac.

**Note:** I have no affiliation with either Airfoil or AirPhones.

Comment: That's great. Gives me something to muck around with in the office on Monday!